# Overlay images javascript with checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```js
//first element price and image
  function Conf_front_lights() {
  //first element price
    var front_lights = 2 ;
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("front_lights");
//check the checkbox
if (checkBox.checked == true){
//if is checked add value to total
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML) + front_lights;
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "https://dummyimage.com/300x300/473847/ff0000.png&text=Red+Front+Lights";
       var src = document.getElementById("overlay");
          // append the image to OverlayDIV
       src.appendChild(img);  
       } else {
// //if is unchecked substract value from total
       document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML) - front_lights;
          //remove Image from Overlay DIV
        $( "overlay" ).remove( ":contains('front_lights')" );
      
      
       }
    }

     function Conf_hood() { 
       var hood = 15 ;
       var checkBox = document.getElementById("hood");
       if (checkBox.checked == true){
       document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML) + hood;
       var img = document.createElement("img");
       img.src = "https://dummyimage.com/300x300/72cfcf/0000ff.png&text=hood";
       var src = document.getElementById("overlay");
       src.appendChild(img);  
       } else {
       document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML) - hood;
        $( "overlay" ).remove( ":contains('hood')" );
      
      
       }
    }

     function Conf_front_spoiler() { 
       var front_spoiler = 60 ;
       var checkBox = document.getElementById("front_spoiler");
       if (checkBox.checked == true){
       document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML) + front_spoiler;
       var img = document.createElement("img");
       img.src = "https://dummyimage.com/300x300/cfcc74/0000ff.png&text=front+spoiler";
       var src = document.getElementById("overlay");
       src.appendChild(img);  
       } else {
       document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML) - front_spoiler;
        $( "overlay" ).remove( ":contains('front_spoiler')" );
      
      
       }
    }

     function Conf_back_lights() { 
       var back_lights = 2 ;
       var checkBox = document.getElementById("back_lights");
       if (checkBox.checked == true){
       document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML) + back_lights;
       var img = document.createElement("img");
       img.src = "https://dummyimage.com/300x300/e68f1e/000000.png&text=back+lights";
       var src = document.getElementById("overlay");
       src.appendChild(img);  
       } else {
       document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML) - back_lights;
        $( "overlay" ).remove( ":contains('back_lights')" );
      
      
       }
    }

     function Conf_back_spoiler() { 
       var back_spoiler = 25 ;
       var checkBox = document.getElementById("back_spoiler");
       if (checkBox.checked == true){
       document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML) + back_spoiler;
       var img = document.createElement("img");
       img.src = "https://dummyimage.com/300x300/e6208d/000000.png&text=back+spoiler";
       var src = document.getElementById("overlay");
       src.appendChild(img);  
       } else {
       document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML) - back_spoiler;
        $( "overlay" ).remove( ":contains('back_spoiler')" );
      
      
       }
    }
```

```css
#overlay{position:relative;border:1px solid #f1f4f9}
#overlay img{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;margin:0 auto}
#overlay img:first-child{position:relative}
#overlay img{background:none!important}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-left">
    <form action="self.php">
     <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Front Car</strong><br />
       <input type="checkbox" name="front_car" onclick="Conf_front_lights()" id="front_lights" value="1"> Red Front Lights  <strong>+ 2 &euro;</strong> <br />
       <input type="checkbox" name="front_car" onclick="Conf_hood()" id="hood" value="2"> Red Hood  <strong>+ 15 &euro;</strong> <br />
       <input type="checkbox" name="front_car" onclick="Conf_front_spoiler()" id="front_spoiler" value="3"> Red Front Spoiler  <strong>+ 60 &euro;</strong> <br />
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Back Car</strong><br />
       <input type="checkbox" name="back_car" onclick="Conf_back_lights()" id="back_lights" value="1"> Red Back Lights  <strong>+ 2 &euro;</strong> <br />
       <input type="checkbox" name="back_car" onclick="Conf_back_spoiler()" id="back_spoiler" value="2"> Red Back Spoiler  <strong>+ 25 &euro;</strong> <br />
      </li>
     </ul>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 text-center">
      <div class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Total: <span id="total" value="3">3</span> &euro;</button></div>
      <div id="overlay"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000000/ff00cc.png&text=Base+Image" /></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

it do math and total is calculated but image overlay dosn`t function if uncheck. I tried to remove child node but if i check first and third and fifth and uncheck the third it will remove the first image.

All the images are PNG and it contains only specific part of the car and the rest of the PNG is transparent.

I work in PHP, i know a little javascript.

I want to remove individually selected PNG`s if they unchecked. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using your selectors correctly. Your container with the id `Overlay` should be selected like this:

`$("#Overlay")`

Secondly the `:contains` selector only works on elements that have text content. You can't apply parameters to a source url and expect the selector to parse that to select an element.

You have a few options, but basically what you need to do is create individual elements that can be selected by the DOM. This means applying an attribute to each image that distinguishes it from every other image. That way you can append and remove it easily.

The below code is an example of how you can manipulate an image tag that you add to the overlay.

```js
let g_box = $("#grill");
let s_box = $("#spoiler");

g_box.on("click", function(e) {
let overlay = $("#Overlay"), checked = $(this).prop("checked");

(checked) ? overlay.append("<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150' id='grill_img'/>") : overlay.find("#grill_img").remove();
})

s_box.on("click", function(e) {
let overlay = $("#Overlay"), checked = $(this).prop("checked");

(checked) ? overlay.append("<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150' style='filter: invert(100%)' id='spoiler_img'/>") : overlay.find("#spoiler_img").remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Overlay">

</div>
<label>Grill</label><input type="checkbox" id="grill">
<label>Spoiler</label><input type="checkbox" id="spoiler">
```

Also, I would advise against using JavaScript and JQuery as you are. My suggestion would be to pick one for this application. It will only serve to confuse and muddy your codebase to use both interchangeably like this.

Comment: Thanks, i tried to make this code generate by PHP but i didn`t get what i want, i only put: let overlay = $(\"#Overlay\"); and if i`ts checked append and remove ... it works fine for me, Thank You. I don`t make the difference between JavaScript and JQuery, just adapt code what i find to my needs.